# Getting the .whl for tensorflow to support all CPU instruction sets

Tags: python, tensorflow

When I start `jupyter-notebook` I see:

```
I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:141] Your CPU supports instructions that this TensorFlow binary was not compiled to use: SSE4.1 SSE4.2 AVX AVX2 FMA
```

When I go to the [`tensorflow` GitHub project page](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/) intending to raise an issue about supporting all CPU instruction sets, it tells me to ask on SO first (so here I am).

1. Why wouldn't `tensorflow` be compiled to support all CPU instruction sets?
2. How would I contact the `.whl` packager to ask them to include all CPU instruction sets? (I signed up to pypi.org but I don't seem to be able to message people through there.

Comment: The released packages are compiled to support a limited number of x86-64 extensions for compatibility, since not all CPUs implement all extensions. In PyPI you can always check the "author" field in the package information (Google Inc. for TensorFlow, email opensource@google.com), but for TensorFlow you would have a better chance [submitting an issue](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues). However this has been discussed many times, if you want a TensorFlow build supporting those instructions you should build it yourself.

Comment: Also since [TensorFlow v1.6.0](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/releases/v1.6.0) prebuilt binaries use AVX instructions (which, btw, made it stop working on my Intel Core i7 930, so the compatibility thing is not just a tale).